# Could someone explain this coffeescript syntax to me?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I'm extending a chrome extension that is written in coffeescript and have come across this syntax:

```
Commands =
  init: ->
    for command, description of commandDescriptions
      @addCommand(command, description[0], description[1])

  availableCommands: {}
  keyToCommandRegistry: {}
```

I'd just like to check the difference between this syntax and a class (which would be like this, hypothetically):

```
class Commands
  init: ->
    for command, description of commandDescriptions
      @addCommand(command, description[0], description[1])

  availableCommands: {}
  keyToCommandRegistry: {}
```

Is it just that the former doesn't have a prototype? am I right in thinking that it's alright to call the methods on the Commands in the top, as in `Commands.init()`. The project I'm working in seems to use both syntaxes so I would like to be sure I understand the implications of each before I use one or another.

Thanks.

Comment: ok. I just reread [the on-topic section of the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I thought questions about programming language syntax were on topic? am I mistaken? I think this is both about a `software tools commonly used by programmers` and (possibly more tenuously) a `specific programming problem` with the problem being unable to figure out the meaning of a syntax construct. In addition I don't think it falls into any of the 7 categories that would deem it off topic. Could someone help me understand (don't want to argue, just want to understand.)?

Comment: The "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" OT reason doesn't make much sense to me. Don't worry about a single close vote, someone could be confused, having a bad day, or made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary implication of the first `Command` is that it is an `Object`, not a `Function`, so there is no way to stamp out instances of it directly.

It is a bit confusing that its `init` method includes `commandDescriptions` (which I can only expect is declared somewhere else) and `@addCommand`, which is not attached to the `Command` object.  If `Command` didn't have `@addCommand`, I would expect that it is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  But as a method that is not declared on `Command` is expected to be present, it looks like the group of functionality in `Command` is meant to be [mixed into](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) another class.

**Edit:**

To clarify, objects *can* have `@variables`. In the `init` function, you would reference `availableCommands` or `keyToCommandRegistry` as `@availableCommands` and `@keyToCommandRegistry`.  However, in this particular example, `@addCommand` is not declared anywhere. I would have expected it to be declared as part of the `Command` object declaration, like:

```
CommandsA =
  init: ->
    for command, description of commandDescriptions
      @addCommand(command, description[0], description[1])

  availableCommands: {}
  keyToCommandRegistry: {}

  addCommand: (command, descriptionInfo, otherDescriptionInfo) ->
    #Does some stuff
```

If you can find where `addCommand` is declared, it would help in understanding how `Command` is intended to be used.

Also of note: since `Command` is an object and not a class, the `availableCommands` and `keyToCommandRegistry` objects can be thought of as static class variables.

Comment: Thank you @aelr this is exactly what I was looking for! so just to check, objects can have methods that can be called on them (such as `init`) but cannot have `@variables` (does that mean that the `this` inside the object scope doesn't refer to the object?). Incidentally it's not quite a mixin but does act somewhat like a singleton with: `root.Commands = Commands` attaching it to the rest of things.